# download folder from aws with express and React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3

I need to download folder from aws s3.

i have route "api/uploadFiles/download/all" who is calling a controller method downloadAll

My controller method call downloadFolder function.

```
downloadAll: async (req, res) => {
        await downloadFolder(req, res)
        res.status(200)
    }
```

My downloadFolder function create archive with content data fils in aws bucket folder.

```
function downloadFolder(req, res) {
    const archive = archiver('zip', { gzip: true, zlib: { level: 9 }});

    const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Prefix: `folder/`,
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                data.Contents.forEach((content) => {
                    const file = s3.getObject({ 
                      Bucket: bucketName, Key: content.Key 
                    }).createReadStream() 
                    archive.append(file, { name: content.Key })
                });
                archive.finalize()
                archive.pipe(res)
                resolve(archive)
            }
        });
    })
}
exports.downloadFolder = downloadFolder
```

My handler in React call route and create zip file for save.

```
const handleDownloadAll = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/uploadFiles/download/all')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
        
            const zip = new JSZip();
            zip.file('download.zip', res.data);
            
            zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
                .then(function(content) {
                    saveAs(content, "download.zip");
                });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

When i unzip my zip file i have a zip file inside. And when i unzip this zip file, i have error : data damaged

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for archiver pipe to be finished, instead of finishing right after you append stream to archive variable:

```
async function downloadFolder(req, res) { // async function
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Prefix: `folder/`,
  };

  const { Contents } = await s3.listObjects(params).promise(); // convert request to promise

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // wrap into a promise
    const archive = archiver('zip', { gzip: true, zlib: { level: 9 } });
    archive.on('finish', () => { // end | close
      resolve(archive); // return to main function
    });
    archive.pipe(res);

    // error handler

    for (const content of Contents) {
      const file = s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName, Key: content.Key
      }).createReadStream();
      archive.append(file, { name: content.Key });
    }

    archive.finalize();
  });
}
exports.downloadFolder = downloadFolder
```

Comment: thx for your help. i think that work. My request size change when i delete or add files in my folder aws but I always have an error when i extract file zip :/


`